# Dockerfile entrypoint bash file that loads .env not visible in container

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to develop a Dockerfile for my application that loads a large number of environment variables after initialisation. Somehow, these variables are not reachable when I later execute the following commands:

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
printenv
```

My environment variables are not visible. If I load the files manually however, they are:

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
source .env
printenv
... environment variables are shown ...
```

This is my dockerfile:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app/
RUN chmod 755 load_env_variables.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/src/app/load_env_variables.sh"]
```

**load_env_variables.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

source .env
python start_application
```

And my .env file contains lines als follows: 'export name=value'.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behavior is that `docker exec -it container_name bash` starts a new bash. A new bash has only the standard environment variables plus the ones specified in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files.
A proper solution for your problem would be to use the option `--env-file` with the `docker run` command. Be aware that the env-file needs to look like this:

```
test1=test1
test2=test2
```

Comment: That is not quite true, you can make test it yourself. `export test=test`, `/bin/bash`, `echo $test`. Still outputs test. I thought the same until I tried it out. Also it's `docker exec -ti container_name bash`.

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly mean. But the `docker exec -it` behaves as though you would ssh into a VM, thus is using a new bash with new environment variables. Nevertheless a proper solution for this is to use the `--env-file` option.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I've thought of the same answer, tested it (insufficiently) and falsely corrected you. As you now said, it isn't just the starting of a new bash that creates a new environment, but the "ssh-ing" into the container. +1 to the `--env-file` option